# Getting homebrew upgrades to complete without link error interruptions?

Tags: upgrade, homebrew

Is there a way to invoke homebrew upgrades without having to handle errors manually? For example, when I run an update with:

```
brew upgrade
```

I get error messages like:

```
Error: You must `brew link libusb' before wine can be installed
```

Is there a way to tell homebrew to try to recover from these errors using the suggested solution without having to do something myself? I'm not customizing my homebrew installations in any way, so the suggested solutions always solve the problem and allow my re-run upgrade command to continue.

Comment: belongs on [apple.SE]

Comment: What does `brew doctor` tell you?